# Do you know how to randomly populate a table with an array of pictures?

Tags: ios, iphone, random, populate

I'm trying to create a memory game and I'm stuck with no idea how to randomly populate my cells with pictures from an array. I've just started out Xcode programming mainly for the iOS and I have searched for days on Stack Overflow but I can't seem to find an answer. Either that or I don't really understand what you professionals have said and explained.

Could anyone kindly please enlighten me?

Comment: I think you need to present a clearer idea of what you're trying to do before we can really help. Can you describe what data you think you will have looks like and how you think you want to present it in your view? If you know those two pieces you can probably find help connecting them together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will take an NSArray containing the pictures and produce a new array containing the pictures in random order. Then, you can save the new array and use it in your data source for your table.

```
NSArray *pictures; //Array containing all of the pictures to display
srandomdev();
NSArray *randomPictures = [pictures sortedArrayUsingComparator:(NSComparisonResult)^(id obj1, id obj2) {
    long val = random();
    if(val & 1) return NSOrderedAscending;
    return NSOrderedSame; //or NSOrderedDescending
}];
```

Comment: OP: If I understand you right, you want to create one of those matching memory games where a user picks two things out of a grid, yes? If so, then I would create an NSArray of UIImage objects that have all the tiles you want (so two of each UIImage, for matching), then use this code to randomize that array. You can then iterate through your grid in order (left to right, top to bottom), assigning the next UIImage in the array to whatever tile you're on.

Comment: Hi The code above returns an error: invalid conversion initializing integer 'int', expected block pointer. Is there a way to resolve this issue?

Comment: You could try removing the return type. The compiler might think it is a cast.

Answer (score 0):

If you always have the same set of elements, and you just want to put them into a randomized order, then I recommend you read up on the Fisher-Yates shuffling algorithm (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher–Yates_shuffle). It's the same process you'd use to randomize a deck of cards in a card game, or any other finite set you want to permute.